# iframe issue on iphone5 by default set the width to 980 px

Tags: html, css, iphone, iframe

When I try to open my link in my `iframe` on an iPhone device so by default it set  the width of src url at 980px.

```
<iframe 
  width="100%" 
  height="700" 
  frameborder="0" 
  marginheight="0" 
  marginwidth="0" 
  scrolling="yes" 
  src="http://example.com" 
  style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0px;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your iFrame in a div with the class video wrapper. Then put this in your CSS:

```
.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 50px;
height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

Hope that helped!